# Error al instalar phpmyadmin 502 bad gateway

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin

estoy aprendiendo a usar Laravel por lo cual quise instalar phpamydmin en la maquina viltual(virtualbox) pero al momento de ejecutarlo en el navegador me sale  **502 bad gateway NGINX**

ya he modificado el archivo **hosts** donde agregue la dirección ip y la url que le correspondía (ya lo había hecho anterior mente con homestead y funciono bien).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de igual manera al archivo **homestead.yaml** de mi proyecto le agregue  el nuevo sitio que seria phpmyadmin.test y su respectiva ruta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la maquina virtual ejecute el comando **vagrant up --provision** y lo unico que me sale al ingresar phpmyadmin.test en el navegar es **502 bad gateway NGINX**

Para Aclarar Estoy Usando **Windows 10** y ejecuto todo los comados atraves de  **Git Bash**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿homestead.test sí funciona?

Comment: siii ,el homestead.test me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: No creo que el problema sea phpmyadmin o su instalación, ¿modificaste algo de la configuración de dicho «host»?

Comment: @Shaz solamente agregue estas 2 lineas 


**192.168.10.10   homestead.test  y 
192.168.10.10   phpmyadmin.test** 


donde puse direcion ip y ruta como se indicaba en la documentación de laravel

Comment: ¿Cuáles dos líneas?

Comment: @Shaz **192.168.10.10 homestead.test y 192.168.10.10 phpmyadmin.test**